# Simple CSS query: vertically float blocks in a container

Tags: css

This should be so simple, but I cannot figure it out...

http://www.coelandscapes.co.uk/ is a quite an old site, with a simple CMS. I'm trying to get the menu to vertically align with the bottom of the logo, but can't use absolute (because the number of elements might change).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is great for vertically aligning items. Add this to your #menu style:

```
#menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-end;
  width: 610px;
  height: 245px;
  padding: 0 0 0 12px;
}
```

You might have to add some vendor prefixes depending on what browser you want to support: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Bingo! I'd not thought about a flexbox... Thank you!

Comment: Additionally you can use [justify-content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to align the menu horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `position:relative` on the parent and the child should have this css:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
```

Comment: That doesn't work - it places all the menu blocks on top of each other.

Comment: Add the position relative to the **parent** of #menu and on `#menu` insted of `transform:translateY` add `margin-top: -100px`. I didnt see that the manu had set height this should work.